# Apply Motion/Trailing Effect on an array of points

Tags: animation, graphics

Say I have an array of points `[(x,y)...]` that sketches an object. I want to create trailing effect when the object moves according to the velocity.

An example would be the following (the black arrow is the velocity),

[image: static]

[image]

Another example that I found on youtube is

[image]

How can I update the array of points given the velocity to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That might possibly be of interest: https://processing.org/examples/storinginput.html - But please provide a reproducible code example, that demonstrates the specific problem in the language of choice. The question is a bit too open, Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Hi, many thanks. I think the example gives what I need.